# How much extra soil do I need to buy to account for settling when prepping a garden bed?

Tags: soil, raised-beds

I can calculate the volumes of the beds easily enough, but I assume that as I install the soil it will settle. In a raised vegetable garden bed I could just top it off next year. In a perennial bed, however, I'd definitely want to get enough so that the soil settles to my desired finished grade.

Is there a generic conversion factor to tell me how much extra soil I'd need to buy?

Comment: The amount of organic matter in the soil may also affect how much the soil settles, although this is usually a factor only if you add fairly significant amounts of compost to the soil when prepping the bed. This settling occurs over a year or more after you've completed the bed, as the compost decomposes.